# jQuery - test if img width is 'more than' and 'less than'

Tags: jquery, html, image, attr

I would like to get action if with attr of an image is between two values : On my code this `.w50` is just on the width attr value = 470px

```
$("img").each(function() {

  var image = $(this);
  if (image.attr("width") == 470) {
      image.parent().addClass('w50');
  }

});
```

how can I write "add this class if attr value is more than 470 and less than 490" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
if ((image.attr("width") >= 470) && (image.attr("width") <= 490))
```

Note that I have included both 470 and 490 because I think this is what you meant.. if you don't need the edges drop both `=`.

More details:

The `&&` (AND) operator means that both conditions have to be true.

`>=` means greater than or equal.

`<=` means less than or equal.

You can read more about [comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison_operators) and [logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical_operators).

Comment: It should be `&&`, not `||`